# Connecting to an FTP site using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ftp

I am trying to connect to an FTP site from my states GIS data center using QGIS. I am new to GIS so I'm not sure if there is a problem with the FTP, a problem with my workflow, or if this site isn't capable of being connected to.

I simply go to *Layer->Add Layer->Add WMS/WMTS Layer* I then create a new server connection and paste the FTP server address (ftp://www.maris.state.ms.us/ftp4/NRCS-SE_2015_DEM_IMG/)

[image]

I then try and connect and get this message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An FTP folder containing IMG files and a WMS/WMTS layer are two very, very different things. If you want to add those IMGs to your project, you'll need to download them from the FTP site and add them in QGIS using the Add Raster Layer command:

[image]